# Changing opacity of header on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some code which moves the header image when the user scrolls. It seems to work fine:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
                var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(),
                    header = $('.site-header');

                header.css('top', -(scrolled) * 0.5 + 'px');

                if (scrolled > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 470) {
                    var scrollPos = scrolled - ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 470);
                    var position = scrollPos / 10;
                    var opacity = (scrollPos * 1) / 470;
                }
            });
</script>
```

I'm trying to get the opacity to change as well, so it fades out when I scroll down. This bit doesn't seem to work.

This full code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/acz13129/1/

There seems to be something in the code already around opacity but it doesn't change and the console throws no errors so I am a bit stuck.

Comment: Where is `.indicator` in your fiddle? I can't find it.

Comment: @MEE Hello. I removed it because I didn't need it. Is that what opacity is being changed? I'm so confused? I was trying to fade out the text/image in the header

Comment: In your fiddle the opacity-change is applied to `.indicator`

Comment: Also your `if` statement not working.

Comment: @MEE Ah, ok. But, I've applied the class to my H1 but the opacity doesn't change when I scroll down: https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/acz13129/2/

Comment: @Pedram Any idea why it is not working? Just to help me on my way to fixing it?

Comment: Okay but can you explain about your logic? `if (scrolled > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 470) {` what's your expect?

Comment: There is something wrong with the calculation, **scrolled: 516.25**, **$(document).height(): 3326**, **$(window).height(): 436**, so when you scroll to the bottom then only the css will applied to the image which is in the header.. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/acz13129/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(),
    header = $('.site-header');

  header.css('top', -(scrolled) * 0.5 + 'px');

  var scrollPos = scrolled - ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 470);
  var position = scrollPos / 10;
  var opacity = ((scrollPos / -1000) - 1.734) * 1.5; // Opacity is in decimals e.g. 0.5
  $('.site-header').css({
    "opacity": opacity,
    "position": position + '%'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 500px;
  line-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper-parallax {
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.content {
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  min-height: 2800px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/DCXgzWc.png);
  background-position-y: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300%;
  background-position-x: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-parallax">
  <header class="site-header">
    <img src="img/ja.svg" width="250px" alt="Anna and James" class="logo">
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: This should be at the calculation part instead of using if statement... Thumbs up.

Comment: Strange, I clicked on the link and it seems to be working fine to me. So does the image blink on and off or does it just not show

Comment: It shows straight away, but any sort of scrolling and it instantly sets the opacity to around -3 so it then is hidden completely, and then doesnt show again unless I refresh. This is on chrome :S

Comment: When fully scrolled to the top the opacity seems to be -3.306

Comment: var opacity = 1-(scrollPos / 1000)

Comment: If this works, please could you consider to tick this question, thanks.

Comment: It pretty much worked, I used a bit of your code and a bit of the original question. The only issue is it's adding a little bit onto the opacity rather than taking away but I think I can sort that. ``` var opacity = (scrollPos * 1) / 470;

  $('.site-header').css({
    "opacity": opacity,
    "position": position + '%'
  });
});```